# Deleting Database in Linq

Tags: asp.net, database, linq

In normal condition, I can add schemas in the dbml file to empty database with code below.

But now when I run this code, I take the error "Cannot drop database "test" because it is currently in use."  How can I do it?

```
Dim db As New UI_Class.UIData
        If db.DatabaseExists Then
            db.DeleteDatabase()
        End If

    db.CreateDatabase()
```

Comment: Check SSMS and see what connections are open to the database.

Answer (score 1):

It might happen as your SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) must be holding it.

Comment: No! SSMS was closed during this proccess

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something is connected to the db.

Common causes are:

1. Some other tool connected
2. Trying to delete the database you connected to.
3. Another user connected to the db.